# How do I use the /testfor command to detect players in an area?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I know you can use

```
/testfor
```

like

```
/testfor @p[r=3]
```

or

```
/testfor @p[x=3,y=3,z=3]
```

but is there a way to use it like
    /testfor @p[x=3-10,y=3-10,z=3-10]

so that it detects players in a certain area?

Answer (score 2):

yes, there is. you have to use the DELTA values, like so:

```
/testfor @p[x=3,y=3,z=3,dx=7,dy=7,dz=7]
```

note that the delta values represent the amount of blocks inbetween the smallest point and the highest point in your cubic selection, thus if you want to area to go from 3 to 10 the delta value is 10 - 3 = 7

*note: testfor is mostly obsolete in modern commands. you might want to have a look into alternatives*

Answer (score -1):

This is for the 1.10 game version :

You combine them so its like (in the square brakcets)  `[x=XCOORDS,y=YCOORDS,z=ZCOORDS,r=RADIUS IN THAT POSITION]` so end result should look like this

```
/testfor @a[x=431,y=4,z=40,r=10]
```

This will test for anyone in a 10 block radius of those coordinates.

Comment: Oh sorry wait i forgot you wanted it at in 3 blocks away so give second

Comment: Cant help you there mate. And i'm sure there was a way ... Best i found was this page =                                 https://gist.github.com/Dinnerbone/3736487